Will $|f|^p$ be in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ provided that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $p>1$?
It's easy to see that the absolute value of a $C^1$ function is not necessarily differentiable at some zero point of the function, for example, $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0.$ I wonder whether $|f|^p$ is differentiable provided that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a real-valued function and $p>1.$ It seems that if $x_0$ is a zero point of $f,$ then the order of the zero of $|f|^p$ at $x_0$ will be greater than $1,$ which causes $|f|^p$ to be differentiable (with zero gradient) at that point. However, I don't know how to put it strictly, can someone help me?

Are you taking about real valued functions? I mean, is $|\cdot|$ the absolute value or a norm?

@copper.hat $|\cdot |$ denotes the absolute value

You are making it more complicated than necessary. The question is if $t \mapsto |t|^p$ is differentiable at $t=0$.

@copper.hat Oh I see! $|f|^p$ is the composition of $|\cdot|^p$ and $f,$ thanks so much!

Let $a(x) = |x|^p$. For $x \neq 0$, $a'(x) = ( \operatorname{sgn} x)p x^{p-1}$, so clearly $\lim_{x \to 0} a'(x) = 0$. The only question is if $a$ is differentiable at $x=0$. For $x \neq 0$, ${a(x)-a(0) \over x} ={|x|^p \over x} = {|x| \over x}x^{p-1}$, hence $a'(0) = 0$.
